# Jquery same class show one hide others jsfiddle included

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a gallery with this code.

It works if i have two separate containers for buttons and contents but is there a way to just use one container for everything?

Also, without using extra classes like (one,two,three,...)

HTML:

```
<div id="content">this is a box</div>
<button>First</button>
<div class="info">hahahaha</div>
<button>Second</button>
<div class="info">hahahaha2</div>
<button>Third</button>
<div class="info">hahahaha3</div>
```

JS:

```
    $(".info").hide();

$("button").click(function () {

    //replace stuff inside #content with .info in the div under each box
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".info"));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MsUVu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$("#content").html($(this).find(".info"));
```

to this:

```
$("#content").html($(this).next(".info").text());
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MsUVu/1/)**

`.find()` goes through the children of an element; you want `.next()` which gets the next sibling element.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood your question, so this is not what you wanted. This just opens/hides the divs under your clicked button. Use the other answer, very concise.

add the following two lines:

```
    $('.info').hide();
    $(this).next('div:first').show();
```

so it looks like:

```
$(".info").hide();

$("button").click(function () {
    $('.info').hide();
    $(this).next('div:first').show();
    //replace stuff inside #content with .info in the div under each box
    $("#content").html($(this).find(".info"));

});
```